How could I disable breakpoints(or make them not visible)?
So, I keep accidentally somehow inserting breakpoints to the left of my screen. I was wondering, is there a way to completely disable them? I have already tried adding this to my init.el file, but to no luck
(setq gud-breakpoint nil)
(setq gud-tooltip-echo-area nil)

I use lsp-mode for C++ debugging, and the breakpoints don't seem to be appearing the same way in non-cpp buffers.

Immediately after you see the breakpoint indicator on the fringe, do M-x view-lossage: that will tell you the last few keystrokes you typed and what commands they ran. That should allow you to debug your problem and figure out how to recover.

Thanks, will try

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373826/how-to-disable-fringe-in-emacs#11480217 seems to work well enough!
It doesn't disable breakpoints, but disabling the fringes seems to do the trick, so I don't accidentally put the breakpoints in the text buffer, and no longer see them(which is enough, the breakpoints don't actually have to be disabled).

Link-only answer, so should be deleted. For a real answer you need to please answer the question, at least by summarizing the relevant info at the link.

What trick is that? DId you just want to hide the visual feedback? Do you not want to disable the breakpoint(s)?

Only wanted to disable the indication, didnt care about the actual breakpoints.

In which case, the title of your question is wrong.

I archieved the same result by doing something else. Sadly, title on stackoverflow can't seem to be editable so.

It is: just hit Edit and edit the title in the box labeled "Title".

I see. Last time it wasnt possible. Thanks!
